# The second root of the number is up to 4 decimal places

Tags: python, python-3.x

I intend to print the fourth number of digits that the user intends to print up to 4 decimal places in the output
How do I get up to four decimal places without using Round() function?

```
import math 
n = int(input('Do you want to calculate the root of a few numbers? --> '))

for i in range(n):
    usrinp = int(input('Enter the number for root --> '))
    x = math.sqrt(usrinp)

    print(x)
```

for example:

Do you want to calculate the root of a few numbers? --> 4

Enter the number for root --> 1

Enter the number for root --> 2

Enter the number for root --> 3

Enter the number for root --> 19

---

output:

1.0000

1.4142

1.7320

4.3588

Comment: Please add some sample inputs and expected outputs to your question. And tell us what's the problem with your code?

Comment: Look up string format mini language: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings

Comment: Regarding your request, I've edited my question.

Comment: I'm beginner at Python and it's a bit hard for me to work exactly with all of my features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get 4 decimal places without `round` function:

```
print('{:0.4f}'.format(x))
```